# Software or programming language used for math calculations?

Tags: math-software

Is there any software or programming lang for getting maths answers step by step?

When I type the question it should give a brief answer,
for example
when I type **(2+2)*2** 
it should show me
(2+2)*2
=(4)*2
=**8**
and it **should not** be like this
(2+2)*2=8
(it **shouldn't** be like a calculator that shows only the final answer).

Comment: Usually if I want to see intermediate steps, I do the intermediate steps. For example, I type $2+2$, the response is $4$. Then I type $4 * 2$, the response is $8$.

Comment: There are software "theorem provers" that can show step-by-step how they solved a problem. I believe a person requires some training in order to use one properly. You might be able to ask such a program to prove the answer your calculator gave; it would then show you, step-by-step, _why_ $(2+2)\times 2 = 8$.

Comment: @DavidK i wish to see the intermediate steps for difficult problems, not for these simple problems.

Comment: Those are also the problems for which I would use my technique. I used a simple example because that was the example you gave. In practice I might evaluate a more complicated expression in one step as part of an even more complex expression.

Comment: @DavidK you thought me wrong i am asking you about the " theorem provers" is it possible to see the intermediate steps for difficult problems?

Comment: Yes, that was the point. A proof _is_ a set of intermediate steps that show a formula to be true. At least some provers should produce a proof as their output; that is what "proving a theorem" usually means. But it has been a long time since I have looked at software of that kind and I cannot tell you much about what would be available today.

Answer (score 0):

For simple queries, [Symbolab](http://symbolab.com) seems like a decent tool. This might be sufficient for your needs. [Cymath](http://www.cymath.com/) seems to be a similar tool.

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) has a paid "Pro" subscription service which can answer some queries step by step as well.

Comment: Is possible to get intermediate steps in Symbolab for calculus?

Comment: I am not a user, but it seems to take derivatives, etc.

Comment: Thank you par , i will try to use and let you know.